# Mixed-effects model: basic questions

Tags: regression, mixed-model, matlab

I am trying to implement a mixed-effects regression model in Matlab to see the correlation between self-reported stress levels and some physiological features. Data comes from a longitudinal study so I have to deal with repeated measures' issues.

I have some knowledge about basic regression models such as OLS or PLSR but I am new to mixed-effects regression models, and I am completely lost. I don't find any good example and I don't know where to start from.

I currently have a data matrix of 34 people with 30 measures of 65 variables for each one of them, and I have several questions.

- Do I have to select a single/or a few variables to regress or can I try to include all the variables in the model?
- Do I have to think about a model (formula) or can Matlab automatically create one?
- Which is(are) the random effect variable? The subjects' id-s?
- How do I know which interaction term to introduce?
- How do I know if I should use a random intercept or s random variable?

I would be very grateful if you could give me some steps to follow.

Thanks,

Comment: It seems to me that this is mostly about the statistics that you want to do, rather than the MATLAB code to do it. If so, you should probably delete MATLAB from the title because questions about software are off topic here.

Answer (score 0):

1. One should choose the variables to include based on theoretical considerations. Try different models with different combinations of variables and check how good the model fit is. You will see that the level of explanatory power varies between the variables. But never include more variables into the model than cases. Rather try to include as few variables as possible to explain the outcome and compare different models.
2. You have to choose the variables based on the theory you have a out the relationship between self-reported stress levels and those physiological features you are interested in. Do you for example think the more stress, the more obese? Go for a linear model with these two variables and some control variables in that case.
3. Control variables. In your case probably personal information like gender, age, weight, education etc.
4. see #2